# Cast multiples columns in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, casting, databricks

I'm on Databricks and I'm working on a classification problem. 
I have a DataFrame with 2000+ columns. I want to cast all the columns that will become features to double.

```
val array45 = data.columns drop(1)

for (element <- array45) {

data.withColumn(element, data(element).cast("double"))

}
 data.printSchema()
```

The cast to double is working but I'm not saving it in the DataFrame called Data. If I create a new DataFrame in the loop ; outside of the for loops my DataFrame won't exist. 
I do not want to use UDF.

How can I solve this ?

**EDIT :** Thanks both of you for your answer ! I don't know why but the answer of Shaido and Raul are taking a bunch of time to compute. It comes from Databricks, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply write a function to `cast` a `column` to `doubleType` and use the function in `select` method.

The function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
def func(column: Column) = column.cast(DoubleType)
```

And then use the function in `select` as

```
val array45 = data.columns.drop(1)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
data.select(array45.map(name => func(col(name))): _*).show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I just add val DF2 = at the beginning of the last line to save the cast to a DF. 
I don't know why but the two others answers are taking a bunch of time and i don't have any result. 
I'm pretty sure that come from Databricks. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes you always have to assign transformation to other variable for saving purpose. Thanks for the upvote and acceptance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the new dataframe to a `var` at every iteration, thus keeping the most recent one at all times.

```
var finalData = data.cache()
for (element <- array45) {
  finalData = finalData.withColumn(element, finalData(element).cast("double"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest use a foldLeft:

```
    val array45 = data.columns drop(1)

    val newData = array45.foldLeft(data)(
          (acc,c) =>
            acc.withColumn(c, data(c).cast("double")))

    newData.printSchema()
```

Hope this helps!