# Scala Databricks: casting all bigint columns to double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types

I refer to this question: [Cast multiples columns in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419530/cast-multiples-columns-in-a-dataframe)

I have a dataframe with many columns. Some beginning columns (say 5) should not be touched because they are ID, name, etc.

From column 6 onward, I would like to cast a column if its datatype is `bigint` to `double` DataTypes.

Currently, I am using:

`val df2 = df.withColumn("col_name", df.col("col_name").cast(DataTypes.DoubleType))`

for each column and it is really time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Exclude first 5 columns, find all ensuing columns with BigInt/Long type

2 - Fold over list of BigInt columns, changing them to Double

```
val df2 = df.schema.drop(5).collect{case c if c.dataType == DataTypes.LongType => c.name}.foldLeft(df){(acc, nxt) => acc.withColumn(nxt, acc.col(nxt).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType))}
```

Comment: Sorry for my noob question but I don't see anything like `BigInt` in your code? How did you do that?

Comment: No problem! `BigInt` is Hive terminology, the Spark-SQL equivalent is `Long`, hence `DataTypes.LongType`. Both represent a 64-bit integer.